# How to pause the program when there's no connection to the website?

Tags: python, web, connection

How can I pause the program when there's no internet connection? The program is taking information from websites(urllib2, beautifulsoup), but if the user lost connection to the website, how do I pause the program until the user enter the word "START"?

Answer (score 0):

Check the html and pause if its empty or detect something(like error code). Then react.

Use also timeout for requests: with curl Im using connection-timeout and max-time timeout for the whole request.

To solve the user input:

```
s = raw_input("Continue?")
if s == "START":
    #re run your code
```

Answer (score 0):

when you request using urllib2 it will use a default timeout usually 3600 seconds because you can change the timeout to someting else

urllib2.urlopen(url[, data[, timeout[, cafile[, capath[, cadefault[, context]]]]])

so you can write something like

```
urllib2.urlopen("www.example.com", timeout=60) # to set a timeout for 60 seconds
```

you can wrap this with a try and except

```
while True: #this can be a loop of all the url you get
 try:
   request = urllib2.urlopen("www.example.com", timeout=60)
   # manipulate the request object 
 except urllib2.URLError, e:
  s = raw_input("timeout detected continue [y/n]")
  if s == "Y":
    continue
  else:
    break
 time.sleep(1)
```